# Ругань на DECLARE, или Как переписать процедуру в транзакцию?

Tags: mysql

Написал свою первую процедуру. По идее с синтаксисом все верно, судя по всем туториалам, мануалам и ссылкам из гугла

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE `category` int(3)  DECLARE `tendertext` text DECLARE `protocoltext` text' at line 4

Сама процедура:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TENDERS()
BEGIN
DECLARE `name` text
DECLARE `category` int(3) 
DECLARE `tendertext` text
DECLARE `protocoltext` text
DECLARE `date` date
DECLARE `filename` text

DECLARE `name_ctender` varchar(255)
DECLARE `category_ctender` int(3)
DECLARE `text_ctender` mediumtext
DECLARE `datetimecreate_ctender` timestamp
DECLARE `protocolfilesrc_ctender` varchar(255)
DECLARE `docfilesrc_ctender` varchar(255)
DECLARE `protocolfiledb_ctender` varchar(255)
DECLARE `docfiledb_ctender` varchar(255)
DECLARE `published_ctender` tinyint(1)

DECLARE A_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT `tender`.`ObjName`, `tender`.`Type`, `tender`.`Text`, `protocol`.`Text`, `tender`.`Date`, `protocol`.`FileName` 
FROM `karles_Tenders` as `tender`, `karles_TendersProtocols` as `protocol`
WHERE `tender`.`Id` = `protocol`.`TenderId`

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE
OPEN A_cursor

read_loop: LOOP

FETCH A_cursor INTO `name`, `category`, `tendertext`, `protocoltext`, `date`, `filename`
IF done THEN
    LEAVE read_loop
END IF
set `name_ctender` := `name`
IF `category` = 0 THEN 
set `category_ctender` := 1
END IF
IF `category` = 1 THEN 
set `category_ctender` := 3
END IF
IF `category` = 2 THEN 
set `category_ctender` := 2
END IF
IF `tendertext` = NULL THEN 
set `tendertext` := ""
END IF
IF `protocoltext` = NULL THEN 
set `protocoltext` := ""
END IF
set `text_ctender` := CONCAT(`tendertext`, `protocoltext`)
set  `datetimecreate_ctender` := UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)

INSERT INTO `r082p_ctender` (`name`, `category`, `text`, `datetimecreate`)
VALUES (`name_ctender`, `category_ctender`, `text_ctender`, `datetimecreate_ctender`)
END LOOP

END
```

Пробовал писать деклэйры и через точки с запятой, все равно выдает ошибку. 
Вообще использование процедуры в данном случае мне не обязательно, тело процедуры будет вызвано лишь однажды, потому можно переписать в транзакцию, но я не знаю, как обойтись без курсора. Тоже интересно услышать советы, как можно заменить курсор

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если судить по тому, что вы привели, то курсор не нужен вообще.

```
INSERT INTO `r082p_ctender` (`name`, `category`, `text`, `datetimecreate`)
SELECT tender.ObjName, 
       CASE tender.Type 
       WHEN 0 THEN 1 
       WHEN 1 THEN 3 
       ELSE tender.type END, 
       CONCAT(COALESCE(tender.Text, ''), COALESCE(protocol.Text, '')), 
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tender.Date)  
FROM karles_Tenders as tender, karles_TendersProtocols as protocol
WHERE tender.Id = protocol.TenderId
```